# My header keep disappearing and it not fix to the correct row

Tags: vba, excel, header

This page is supposed to show the selected policy number/plan details. Like the different components such. But it varies based on the policy number. Some can have 1 or some may have more than that. I managed to get the plan/component to work based on the number of component per policy number. But my funds invested header and component header cant display the value according to the policy number.

Display problem: 
I tried doing the fund invested value but my component header will be gone. If not will be my component value will be place together with the funds invested header. What wrong with it ?

**Codes:**

```
Sub LinkName()

    Dim i As Long, k As Long, b As Long, c As Long, f As Long  'For loop variable
    Dim ShtUsedRange, ShtUsedRangeCol
    Dim rw As Variant
    Dim policynum As Variant
    Dim lookup_range As Range
    Dim box As Variant
    Dim counter As Long, DetailsCounter As Long, FundInfoCounter As Long, FundAllocationCounter As Long
    Dim a As Long, d As Long, e As Long, p As Long, m As Long

    ShtUsedRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'Count the used rows in the Activesheet
    ShtUsedRangeCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    'Count the used Column in the Activesheet

    rw = ActiveCell.Row
    'Row number of the Selected Cell

    policynum = ActiveSheet.Cells(rw, 3).Value
    'policynum of the row selected

    Set lookup_range = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Range("c4:iv30000")
    'set the range of the Policy details to search from

    box = Application.VLookup(policynum, lookup_range, 1, False)
    'to match the policy num to the policy details

    counter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'MsgBox counter

    k = 16
    Do While (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Range("B" & k) <> "")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Rows(k & ":" & k).Delete
    Loop
    'delete the previous set of components

    a = 16 'Start of Plan/Component
    d = 21 'Start of Funds Invested

    'Based On PolicyComponents Table
    For i = 4 To counter Step 1

        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Cells(i, 3).Value = box Then

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(a, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Cells(i, 4).Value
            'Policy Components
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(a, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Cells(i, 5).Value
            'Status
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(a, 4).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Cells(i, 6).Value
            'Life Assured
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(a, 5).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Cells(i, 7).Value
            'Benefit Amt/ Sum Assured
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(a, 6).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Cells(i, 8).Value
            'Premium
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(a, 7).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Cells(i, 9).Value
            'Single Premium
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(a, 8).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Cells(i, 10).Value
            'Premium Cessation Date
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(a, 9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Cells(i, 11).Value
            'Risk Commencement Date
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(a, 10).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Cells(i, 12).Value
            'Risk Cessation Date
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(a, 11).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Cells(i, 13).Value
            'Est. Total Paid

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Rows(a + 1 & ":" & a + 1).Insert
            'insert blank lines
            a = a + 1


    End If

    Next i
    'End of Plan/Component Table

    'For Policy Details
    DetailsCounter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For b = 4 To DetailsCounter Step 1

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 3).Value = box Then
    'POLICY VIEWER
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(2, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 1).Value
            'Policy Owner Name
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(3, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 2).Value
            'Plan Type
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(4, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 3).Value
            'Policy Num***
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(5, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 4).Value
            'Policy Status
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(6, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 5).Value
            'Payment Method
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(7, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 6).Value
            'Paid-To-Date
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(8, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 7).Value
            'Frequency
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(9, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 8).Value
            'Premium $
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(10, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 9).Value
            'Amt In Suspense
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(11, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 16).Value
            'Servicing Agent
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(7, 9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 10).Value
            'Life Assured
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(8, 9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 11).Value
            'Joint Life Assured
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(9, 9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 12).Value
            '2nd Joint Life Assured
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(10, 9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 13).Value
            'Joint PolicyOwner
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(11, 9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 14).Value
            'Assignees
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(12, 9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Cells(b, 15).Value
            'Trustees
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(2, 9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyValues").Cells(b, 4).Value
            'Est ILP Surrender Value
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(3, 9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyValues").Cells(b, 5).Value
            'Gross Surrender Value
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(4, 9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyValues").Cells(b, 6).Value
            'Gross Cash Bonus
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(5, 9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyValues").Cells(b, 7).Value
            'Total Cashback
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(6, 9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyValues").Cells(b, 8).Value
            'Est Total Paid
    End If
    Next b
    'End of Policy Details (B2:I12)
    =====================================================================
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxI think problem lies herexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    =====================================================================
    p = 21
    'For Funds Invested table
    Do While (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Range("B" & p) <> "")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Rows(p & ":" & p).Delete
    Loop

    FundInfoCounter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fund Information").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For c = 4 To FundInfoCounter Step 1

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fund Information").Cells(c, 3).Value = box Then

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(d, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fund Information").Cells(c, 4).Value
    'Funds Invested
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(d, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fund Information").Cells(c, 5).Value
    'Unit Balance
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(d, 4).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fund Information").Cells(c, 6).Value
    'Bid Price
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(d, 5).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fund Information").Cells(c, 7).Value
    'Unit Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(d, 6).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fund Information").Cells(c, 8).Value
    'Unit Value as at

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Rows(d + 1 & ":" & d + 1).Insert
    'insert blank lines
    d = d + 1

    End If
    Next c
    'End of Fund Invested Table

    m = p + 3
    e = 24 ' start of component 
    'For Components Table
    Do While (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Range("B" & m) <> "")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Rows(m & ":" & m).Delete
    Loop

    FundAllocationCounter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fund Allocation").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For f = 4 To FundAllocationCounter Step 1

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fund Allocation").Cells(f, 3).Value = box Then

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(e, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fund Allocation").Cells(f, 4).Value
    'Component
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(e, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fund Allocation").Cells(f, 5).Value
    'Fund Invested
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(e, 6).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fund Allocation").Cells(f, 6).Value
    'Percentage

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Rows(e + 1 & ":" & e + 1).Insert
    'insert blank lines


    End If
    Next f
    'End of Components Table

    =====================================================================
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    =====================================================================

    End Sub
```

[image: Here is the display layout]

Comment: `Here is my codes`? You have to ask a more specific question. As it is now, someone would have to run through all your code just to understand what you are asking. Make it easy to help you by just supplying the parts of the code that are not working as you excpect them to, and explain that specific problem in more detail.

Comment: @OlleSjögren The problem is i dontknow what is wrong with it. Like there was no error msg pop out or anything. But i think is that part of codes got problem.

Comment: hahahah " I dont know what's wrong with it" :D :D can you at least tell what are you trying to achieve? I don't think anyone will understand your business logic with 4 lines :) please tell us what's not wroking

Comment: Towards the end of your code you are deleting a number of non-blank rows in the *Policy Viewer* worksheet. Is this what is creating the problem with retrieving the values associated with the *Policy Number*? Can you retrieve the values and write them in (instead of using formulas)  or retrieve them with formulas and revert the formulas to their values before you delete the rows?

Comment: @krish In this page, it is taking data from 5 different sheets. For example, i click on the policy number and it will show me everything under this policy number, like the components header in row 25 and funds invested in row 23. But it is not necessary that they have data on that. Problem now is that if i click on policy num, row 23 and 25 data will be gone or combine together as one.

Comment: You have hardcoded the rows to start deleting and inserting rows. The issue may be here. I would suggest setting a cell in each of the row headers that you want to start to delete down from as a named range and from that, it can be used as a reference cell to give you the correct row to start from.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what the different parts of you code do - I suggest you start by stepping through your code from the top to see where the problems start and what you can do to correct them. Then ask questions about any problems you can't solve on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this question belongs to the code review section but i will give it a try.

Your problem is you are loosing track of your last used row number. You start adding rows and then deleting rows without.....i don't know whats in your mind :D

Check this line:

```
p = 21
'For Funds Invested table
Do While (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Range("B" & p) <> "")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Rows(p & ":" & p).Delete
Loop
```

You are telling blindly your funds invested table starts at row 21 regardless how big your plan summary is and start deleting rows!!!!. Your plan summary could end up having 100 lines. >> **"you need to know/take a note of your last row"**

Check this code (same issue):

you are inserting new rows in the funds invested section as long as there are enough data available from the next sheet.

```
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(d, 6).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fund Information").Cells(c, 8).Value
'Unit Value as at

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Rows(d + 1 & ":" & d + 1).Insert
'insert blank lines
d = d + 1

End If
Next c
'End of Fund Invested Table
```

and then you are telling vba your "component" section starts at row 24 regardless how many rows you have inserted in the "funds invested section" **absolutely no good**

```
m = p + 3
e = 24 ' start of component 
'For Components Table
Do While (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Range("B" & m) <> "")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Rows(m & ":" & m).Delete
Loop
```

**m and e** should be at least greater or equal to d because d is the last row number you were using/inserting. it cannot be p because p is still 21.

You have three options.

- Create named Ranges for your tables/Sections. Get the row number and insert rows after in the range. This way you are not using blind row numbers but dynamically getting the Sections.
- OR KNOW which row you used at last. Don't use all of the A~Z alphabets as variable and loose track. Just keep one Variable as row number then you know where and what row you are deleting/inserting.
- Learn to debug use the step by step line (f8) and check the values of your variables. check which rows are affected. Might help you to understand more logic